# ndb.ComputedProperty from ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_true=now) first call error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I have an ndb.Model that has a ndb.DateTimeProperty and a ndb.ComputedProperty that uses the ndb.DateTimeProperty to create a timestamp.

```
import time
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Series(ndb.Model):
    updatedDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    time = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: time.mktime(self.updatedDate.timetuple()))
```

The problem I am having is on the first call to .put() (seriesObj is just be an object created from the Series class)

```
seriesObj.put()
```

The ndb.DateTimeProperty is empty at this time. I get the following error:

```
File "/main.py", line 0, in post series.put()
time = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: time.mktime(self.updatedDate.timetuple()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timetuple'
```

I can tell that this is just because the ndb.DateTimeProperty is not set but I don't know how to set it before the ndb.ComputedProperty goes to read it.

This is not an issue with the ndb.ComputedProperty because I have tested it with the ndb.DateTimeProperty set and it works fine.

Any and all help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation into this issue, to avoid the default value from being evaluated when the module is imported. I have just gone with setting the initial value of `updatedDate` when creating a new `Series`.

```
import datetime
series = Series(updatedDate = datetime.datetime.now())
series.put()
```

I would have preferred a more "don't think about it" solution using `_pre_put_hook` but in tests, it did not appear to be called before the evaluation of the `time` `ComputedProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem, it was actually a simple solution. I simply edited the line

```
updatedDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

To include the default parameter

```
updatedDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Also had to import the datetime module

```
import datetime
```

Once this was updated, the object was then able to be created without error. Now it will not only run without error but also set the initial value of updateDate to the current date and time. To bad the auto_now parameter does not do this automatically.

Thank you to all of you who took your time to help me with this solution!

Comment: I think you might have a problem with this.  The default value for updatedDate will be evaluated at import time and not instance creation.  If the computed property is evaluated before the updatedDate then on entity creation your time property will have the time of that the model was imported - time of first request/instance startup.  Which could be days old.

Comment: I am unable to test this, as in my environment I am not getting the original error you where getting so updatedDated was being evaluated first for me.

Comment: You're not getting the error when you call .put()? I've updated my original post to make the reproducing steps a little more clear. I'm about to edit my answer again to include a new idea I have yet to test but think could work.

Comment: Yeah I don't get the error when using your original example.  As I said it all to do with order of evaluation.  Python dictionary orders will differ.  On my system the datetimeproperty is being evaluated first, so computed property doesn't fail.  Thats why I suggested you check the calculated `time` is in fact correct after an update. Thats why I also mentioned the default value for DatetimeProperty is evaluated at import time, and if that value is used when you do the put you will have an incorrect value for time.  Some testing will show if this is the case or not.

Comment: That is odd that it works that way, I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the _pre_put_hook to set the value of currentDate just before .put() is called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True) is not resolved until put time. The same with the computed property.  As you have found out the ComputedProperty is also evaluated at the same time.

However here is the wart, the order of declaration does not appear to be preserved, (I have found this when trying to generate forms based on the properties of a model automatically).  Properties are not stored in an OrderedDictionary so the order is not guaranteed so you will find the `ComputedProperty` `time` is being resolved before the udpatedDate is being resolved.

How should you get around this?

Not sure, in theory you could use a Factory to create `Series` entity each time you need to create one, and explicitly set the DateTime when you create the object. This will mean when you put the object the ComputedProperty will get resolved and will probably only be out by a fraction of a second.

However this may not ensure that the ComputedProperty is correctly evaluated on future updates.  More than likely the ComputedProperty will use the old value and not the new value of updatedDate because you still can't force the order of property evaluation.

Personally I think this is a bug or a much needed enhancement to the ndb Model class.

This probably means you should use a method of Series say `update` which you always call instead of put which explicitly sets updateDate before calling put.

ie

```
def update(self):
   self.updatedDate = datetime.now()
   self.put()
```

Probably a better way would be to use a pre_put hook to explicitly set udpateDate before calling put.  I haven't tested this to make sure it is called before property evaluation, but my guess is it will

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__pre_put_hook

Messy - I know ;-)

Comment: woudn't a 'pre put hook' be more appropriate in this case?!

Comment: That's what I said at the end of my answer.  Felt it was worth covering what is going on.

Comment: I have always liked the idea of factories creating classes but hopefully my submitted answer holds up for me. Thank you for the help though! :)

Comment: I would check that the computed value is correct after next update, if so then you have definately got the better answer ;-)